# I need a configurable IDE for my personal Tiger Compiler?

Tags: compiler-construction, ide, tiger

I made a tiger compiler, so i need a simple IDE to configure it to work with my compiler, I thought using Notepad++ but I couldn’t find a way to underline or mark the errors on the text. Any suggestions???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a great free app, [Programmer’s Notepad 2](http://www.pnotepad.org), does everything I want and more.

Answer (score 0):

[Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/) is generally the suggest for a general purpose IDE.